# Groovy script to compare response xml with another xml file in the local directory

Tags: xml, groovy, compare

we have a hub upgrade in our project, for this

before upgrade, we need to run all the services(83) and store the response in our local directory

after upgrade,
we need to run all the services with same request and compare the current response with before upgrade response

For the above,

Please some one share groovy script to do this, I am using soap ui 5.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

i found this i hope it will help you :

You can use the Groovy XMLUnit utility like this:

```
XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true)
XMLUnit.setIgnoreComments(true)
XMLUnit.setIgnoreDiffBetweenTextAndCDATA(true)
XMLUnit.setNormalizeWhitespace(true)

XMLUnit.compareXML(expectedXml, actualXml)
```

To compare XML files while ignoring the syntactical differences.

Answer (score 0):

Use XMLUnit http://www.xmlunit.org/
Copy XMLUnit jar file under SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext, then restart soapui.

```
def diff = XMLUnit.compareXML(originalXMLString, responseXMLString)
assert diff.identical()
```